# How can I make changes to android screen brightness persistent?

Tags: android, brightness, screen-brightness

I've managed to change screen brightness within an activity (and by extension the entire app) using the following code:

```
Settings.System.putFloat(this.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, ((float)LocationService.settings.screenBrightness));

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
float brightness = someValue;
lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

However, as soon as I close the app the brightness returns to its previous settings. Is there anyway to make these changes persist outside of the lifecycle of the app?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is identical to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737579/83446 Did you even run a search first? Somebody mark as duplicate.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli: I don't think this is a duplicate because the question you linked to is about `changing screen brightness programmatically` while here the poster is asking about `how to make change to Android screen brightness persistent`.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli: Actually, I did perform a search. In fact, I read that exact question. However, as Mudassir pointed out, my issue is not simply adjusting brightness within the app; the problem lies in making those changes last even after the app has been paused or stopped.

Comment: Point taken. You are right they are different points. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here maybe help you:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();  
layoutParams.buttonBrightness = value;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);

int brightnessLevel = 255;
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightnessLevel);
```

You will need the WRITE_SETTINGS permission set in your AndroidManifest.xml

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-system-screen-brightness-using.html

Answer (score 0):

Settings application does it this way:

```
private static final int MINIMUM_BACKLIGHT = android.os.Power.BRIGHTNESS_DIM + 10;
private static final int MAXIMUM_BACKLIGHT = android.os.Power.BRIGHTNESS_ON;

System.putInt(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, value + MINIMUM_BACKLIGHT);
```

but I suspect you cannot change a System Settings without having system shared user id

Answer (score 0):

Provide the permission in androidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

And provide a integer number between 0 to 255

```
//number>=0 && number<=255
//If you have passed context then you can use context.getContentResolver()
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cgetContentResolver(),
            android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
            number);
```