# How to dim a screen on click of a button in android?

Tags: android, button, screen-brightness

How do i darken/dim the current screen on click of a button. PLease help me.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html) tutorial will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646865/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-as-with-the-power-widget

Comment: another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791340/adding-screen-brightness-controls-to-android-application

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing screen brightness programmatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737579/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution, though it may not be the best:

create styles.xml under res/values. Add the following code:

```
<style name="Theme.Translucent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/cache_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
 </style>
```

Note that `@color/cache_color` is `<color name="cache_color">#00000000</color>`. Now clicking your custom button should send an intent to an activity (e.g., FooActivity). So declare this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.FooActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent"></activity>
```

and voila, the screen is dimmed when your button's listener is called!

Comment: This is faux dimming and not a proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lparams = getWindow().getAttributes();  
lparams.dimAmount=1.0f; 
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lparams);
```

The dim amount 0 means no dimming, and the dim amount 1.0f means complete dimming.  Any value in between is the corresponding percentage of dim.

Just add this code to the button you want.

Comment: @SherazKhilji call dialog.setContentView before setting dimAmount

Comment: @jjyao i have solved this problem. The thing was that i was in the background thread when i was calling this but once i moved this piece of code into the UI thread then it worked. Thanks