# Make the background behind a AlertDialog black or opaque without replacing with Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to make the background behind an AlertDialog opaque or black without using a Dialog / CustomDialog, I currently have this,

```
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

in my style which I assign to the constructor of the AlertDialog. but it is not dark enough and users can still see information which I do not want them to yet. To be honest my reason for not wanting to use a Dialog is that I have already got everything working with the AlertDialog and thought it would be a good idea to check if anyone knew a quick way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dimActivity(Dialog dialog, float dimAmount) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.dimAmount = dimAmount;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
}
```

dimAmount: 0 - no dimming, 1.0f full dimming. You can check this: [How to dim a screen on click of a button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810575/how-to-dim-a-screen-on-click-of-a-button-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

use this code this might help you

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```