# Turn on Display Ambient programmatically

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I tried search but I didn't search anything about it.

Can I turn on my ambient display with code? I think do a service to turn on when I proximity my hand in device like Motorola.

Thanks advance

Comment: You mean to dim the screen? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810721/603270

Comment: No, I told about the Ambient Display in lock screen.. This a black and white screen in lollipop

Comment: http://www.androidcentral.com/ambient-display-nexus-6   this ?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this by code nor without root...

Comment: Yes it, but I want turn on in run time with code.. I want do one service to turn on this display

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by calling

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DOZE_ENABLED, on ? 1 : 0);
```

Unfortunately, writing vale to Secure setting is not allowed on a non-root device.