# How to set screen brightness inside android application locally

Tags: android

I want to set the brightness of my android application only and not my phone. How do I change the brightness of my android application such that it does not effect my mobile phone brightness?

Comment: You have to reset the brightness settings in onPause of your activity and apply again in onResume

Comment: I didn't understand, you are trying to **only** change your app brightness?

Comment: @Lazy: I have this feature in my camera application, because not all android devices have light sensors and during daytime outdoor photography one might need full-brightness while taking pictures.

Comment: @Lazy : Yes, I want only change(adjust) my app brightness not my mobile.

Comment: @janak: You mean change the phone's brightness when your app is running. :)

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal : No. dont change phone brightness. only change Application brightness. Without any permission.

Comment: @Janak: Thats what i explained in my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to give any permission only set Following Params in your Seekbar's Method

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      float BackLightValue = (float)arg1/100;
      BackLightSetting.setText(String.valueOf(BackLightValue)); // BackLignt is Textview to display value

      WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes(); // Get Params
      layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue; // Set Value
      getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams); // Set params


     }
```

Comment: when I close application and open again brightness is 0 or what ever I change is there.

Comment: Its always Start by given Default not 0 and if u want to start it by system then get System's Brightness and set to params  int systemvalue= android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);

Comment: The code @SANU provided is Plagiarised from [http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/02/change-system-screen-brightness-using.html](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/02/change-system-screen-brightness-using.html) and its manifest clearly has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`

Comment: @SANU: why do you think there is no permission required? Like android will just let you change the device's brightness?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal If we want to change Whole System's brightness then we required permission otherwise not ...and this code is work for me

Answer (score 2):

Get and Save the current brightness of your device, then  change the brightness of the device(when your app starts running), and when your application closes revert back to the original brightness using the saved brightness level.

To Get Screen Brightness Level:

```
int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
```

To Set Screen Brightness Level:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContext().getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, value); //<-- 1-225
```

App manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

or

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = curBrightnessValue/100.0f; //<-- your value here
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

here is a [tutorial link](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-change-screen-brightness-programmatically/)

[Another SO Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18312609/3326331)

P.S: you will have to handle all events like `onPause()`, `onResume()`, `onBackPressed()` etc