# How to make Screen become a flashlight?

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight, android-screen

I want to do what [this app - Screen Flashlight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andronicus.torchscreenonly&hl=en) does. I want to make the screen a bright flashlight. I am thinking should I just do an `ImageView` that is bright white in color - what color do I use? or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can just try it. If you run into a problem, then you can post here. As it is, it's not clear what help you need.

Comment: Ok..I saw the app you post...My quick advice would be...Just use `white` background (on any layout) and ask phone permission for max brightness..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just thought this idea after reading your question and I don't guarantee that it's the best way to do it.

Try something like this:-

1. Make an activity which uses full screen of the phone. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat) to do this.
2. Increase the brightness level of the phone to 100%. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically) to do this.
3. Use pure white color(#ffffff) as background in the parent view.