# adjust brightness of LCD to minimum without seekbar in android device

Tags: android, eclipse, screen-brightness

GOOD DAY! im new in android programming, just want to ask this question.

adjusting the brightness of lcd/led to minimum in just 1 button?
i am planning to make an application to save battery life for my own device.
if it is possible please teach me how thank you!

Comment: Take a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically

Comment: @vishnus im sorry kinda new in java and android programming so maybe i am missing the basics. i barely understand the post with the marked answer but i don't know how to put it on a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Brightness Reference [Developer link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness)

> 0 = dark bright.
>
> 1 = full bright.

```
    click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
            layoutParams.screenBrightness = 0;        //brightness level
            getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i added your code to my onclick and there is no error but my problem now is it doesnt auto generate the apk fil on bin folder. maybe there is missing?

Comment: i cleaned the project then it regenerates the apk from the bin file. thank you! one more question, when i close the app the brightness turns back to normal, what should i do to make it stay in minimum even app closed?