# Programmatically change torch brightness in Nougat

Tags: android, brightness, flashlight

In Android Nougat you can set the torch brightness yet I cannot find any examples of code that can do this. I've searched git and the Android developer API. Does anybody know how to change the torch brightness programmatically?

Comment: Have u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically

Comment: That link is for screen brightness not torch brightness.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is even possible, as I've never seen anything like this, when we're talking about the flash(light) on the back on the phone. Nor can I find anything about it searching on Google. Maybe something like that can be achieved by modulating the flashlight (turning it on/off again very rapidly), although that would probably very performance intensive if it's even possible.

Comment: There's no API for this.

Comment: I thought adjusting the torch brightness was part of Nougat so assumed it would be in the API. Maybe adjusting torch brightness is just for Nougat on Samsung phones.