# How can I control the brightness of the device screen from my application in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, screen, device, brightness

I am making a simple app in which I want that when I press a button the brightness of the device is set to maximum and when I press it again it goes back to how it was before. but I can't find anywhere on the internet how to do this, I've been trying several ways and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the System Brightness Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to change brightness

```
@Composable
fun UpdateBrightness() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        setBrightness(context, isFull = true)
        onDispose {
            setBrightness(context, isFull = false)
        }
    }
}

fun setBrightness(context: Context, isFull: Boolean) {
    val activity = context as? Activity ?: return
    val layoutParams: WindowManager.LayoutParams = activity.window.attributes
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = if (isFull) 1f else WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE
    activity.window.attributes = layoutParams
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    UpdateBrightness() // Set maximum brightness by default
    ...
}
```

The code is taken from this article: https://medium.com/@yhdista/change-the-brightness-for-the-screen-thinking-in-compose-84378dce3b6c

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Mikhail answer. You may have to dig a little bit for activity context, if using fragments

```
    private fun getActivityContext(currentContext: Context): Activity? {
    var context: Context? = currentContext
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is Activity) {
            return context
        }
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```