# In Android 10, is it possible to reboot or shutdown automatically?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-api-30

I know that many callbacks are blocked at API 30 level.

I am trying to develop it for the purpose of using it for the DID panel, not for the purpose of uploading it to the Google store.

I want Android to turn on the screen at 9:00 in the morning and turn it off by 6:00 PM.
need some way to solved this problem.
(Entire OS, not screen)

Comment: Turning on the *screen*, or the entire OS?

Comment: I mean entire OS!! when it's hard to use it, next is Screen control

Comment: You'll need root, and even then you likely only get automatic shutdown, not automatic scheduled start. If the device doesn't have a native scheduled power on/off feature, just switch the screen brightness https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Turning on the entire OS at a certain time is impossible.  The machine is off, there's no way to run your code to turn it on.  There is a solution though-  turn your device on permanently (so it boots when it gets power) and plug it into an electrical socket with a timer, like people use to turn on lights when on vacation.

Comment: actually I have some app for automatically shutdown, and boot when I want it
But it's not clearly works.
I mean not correct time, when I set 9:00am 2~3day later example... 9:20am, 9:30am, 9:01am random booting and shutdown
I don't have the app code, but it seems to be using adb to make it work.

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="com.ebanswers.timetask.receiver.AdbReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.ebanswers.plus.wireless_adb" />
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: <receiver
            android:name="com.ebanswers.timetask.receiver.ShutdownReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>