# How to turn off screen of android phone programmatically?

Tags: android-screen-support, android-screen

How to turn off screen of android phone programmatically? I tried using following code with no luck

```
PowerManager mPowerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MYTAG");

mWakeLock.acquire();
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you expected that aquiring a partial wakelock would turn the screen off(?) The documentation for `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` even says _"Ensures that the CPU is running; the screen and keyboard backlight will be allowed to go off"_. "Will be allowed to" does not mean the same thing as "Will".

Comment: will setting brightness to zero work. I wonder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737579/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android/6757206#6757206

Check this answer.

Comment: @rahulroy9202 setting brightness to 0 will dim the screen to its lowest values, it won't turning it off

Comment: @user3480011 reached something ?!!