# How to changed system brightness to the maximum programatically in android

Tags: java, android

I want to change system brightness to the maximum when an activity is launched.
I use following examples but they didn't work properly .

Also the system brightness shouldn't change when an application is running.

[Change the System Brightness Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically)

[changing screen brightness programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737579/changing-screen-brightness-programmatically-in-android)

How could I achive this process . Any ideas about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = (float)WindowManager.LayoutParams.BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

You should note that this method doesn't change system settings, and the brightness will be back to normal once the activity is paused or destroyed,

Honestly, I don't remember how to change system settings' brightness, but once I find it out,I will post another answer.

If you want to change brightness back to normal then replace `BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_FULL` with `BRIGHTNESS_OVERRIDE_NONE`.

Hope this helps :D